# python list TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list, file, loops

I made this code in python but it has much errors that i want you to check it for me as I'm new at python

```
for i in range(phones):
    pho = int(raw_input( "Phone Number %d : " % (i+1)))
    phNums.append(pho)
    for name in range(phot):
        name1 = '{0}/phone.txt'.format(pathname)
        file = open(name1, 'w')
        file.write = (pho)
        file.close()
```

First issue that when i run the script i had this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    file.write = (pho)
AttributeError: 'file' object attribute 'write' is read-only
```

The script should do this scenario :
First the user give the number of Perfixes and the count of the progs
The script will count phot which it the progs / phones
then the user will give each phone number
the script will take the first number and write it in the text file "phone.txt" on the folders 1 2 3 until reach phot count of folders then move to the next number and continue writing to next count of folders ... etc

please check what is the issue with the code

Comment: Change `for name in phNums[i]:` to `for name in phNums:`

Comment: `file.write` is a function (technically, `write` is a method of the `file` object), so you call it like `file.write('some text')` to write the string `some text` to the file. But `file.write = (pho)` attempts to replace that method with whatever happens to be in `pho`, in this case an `int`. And the `file` object is smart enough to not let you do that. BTW, it's not a good idea to use `file` as a name for your own variables because it's the name of a standard class.

Answer (score 0):

`phNums.append(pho)` adds ints to your list `phNums`, you then try to iterate over `phNums[i]` which is each int in your list which you cannot do and why you get the error.

Just iterate over each element directly:

```
for i in phNums:
    name = '{}phone.txt'.format(i) # i is an int so use str.format to concat
```

Or looking at your code, you may have meant to iterate over a list of names that is not provided in your code.

Comment: the error has gone but this error appeared TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: i is an int so you have to cast as a string or use str.format like in my example

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple error that has already been answered sufficiently, so rather than give you a direct answer, I want to direct you through my debugging process. Hopefully this will save time in the future.

First step is to check where the error occurred:

```
for name in phNums[i]:
```

Ok, now what was the error?

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The "for" statement will iterate over a given iterable and is generally like this:

```
for _item_ in _iterable_
```

Now we know which part of the line to look at. What type is `phNums[i]` ? 
`phNums` is defined earlier as a list, but with `phNums[i]`, we want to find the type of the items in that list. It appears that the only time the script adds to the list is when appending `pho`, which is an int.

There's the issue, you're trying to iterate over an int item! The error makes sense now, but how should we fix it?

note: I tried going further, but your description is unclear. Do you want the folder structure to be:

```
1/phone.txt
2/phone.txt
3/phone.txt
```

where `phone.txt` contains the phone number in each?

Comment: yes this is the structure , for example if the user entered those values ( progs=3 , phones=3 , ph 1 = 00 , ph2 = 01 , ph3 = 02 ) , phot will be 3/3 = 1 so the script would copy ph1 and paste it in 1/phone.txt , then copy ph2 to 2/phone.txt . That's the idea

Comment: This still isn't making sense to me. What do you intend for `phot` to do? It's completely unused in your code.

Comment: Another problem you may run into, you need to create directories before you can write files into them, `open` won't create a directory AND open a file (see `os.mkdir` and `os.makedirs` for directory creation). This may not be an issue if you have all directories created before running the script though.

Comment: to make it clear if the user put in progs 10 phones 2 phot will be 5 and the number ph1 will be copied in folders 1-5 , which mean phot is the variable which decides how many folders this number will be copied to

Comment: So, rather than `for name in phNums` which doesn't make sense, it sounds like you need that to be `for name in range(phot)`. Don't forget that `name` will be an int and it needs to be inserted into the filename similar to @Padraic 's answer

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering but could you help editing the code I'm really new and confused with the loops , Please if you could edit the code for what you are suggesting ?

Comment: Your second `for` loop is the one that needs to be modified. See @Paidric's answer for how to format the filename (for a file within a directory, you want to open something like "directory_name/filename.txt", note the `/`)

Comment: I have edited the code as you can see above and got the updated error above ? what do you think about the loop in this way ?

Comment: for pathname it is mentioned in the first place in the code , and i have changed name to name1 cuz i used name before in the loop before this one

Comment: See the [File Object documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) for information on how to manipulate file objects.

Comment: I am going to stop helping in this thread, because you have solved your initial error. I don't intend to write your program for you, but to give you the tools necessary to fix it yourself.

Comment: I read this docs but i have given the write attribute , why it is giving me that it's read-only ?